# How to find the o365 users with one license but not the other

Tags: powershell, office365, user-accounts

I have a number of o365 account with A1 license or A1 and A1plus license assigned. I need to ONLY find the users with A1 license and add the A1plus license to them.

Below PS run on 10 test users with the mixture of A1 and A1+A1plus license is still showing all of them.

```
Get-msoluser -all | 
    Where-Object {$_.userprincipalname -match '@students.test.com' -and 
    ($_.licenses).accountskuid -match 'test:A1' -and 
    ($_.licenses).accountskuid -notmatch 'test:A1plus'}
```

I expect to only see the users with A1 license instead of users with various licenses where one of them is A1.

Comment: It sounds like you want the users who have only one total license assigned where that one license happens to be this specific incorrect license. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi. Yes. This is correct. I only need to find the users where they ONLY have A1 license assigned and add A1 plus license to them.

Comment: Instead of using `-notmatch`, you can use `-notcontains`. Since `accountskuid` will likely contain a collection, `-notmatch` will be true on at least one of the items. So overall, it will always evaluate to true.

Comment: Dear AdminOfThings. You are awsome. -notcontains worked like a charm. Big THank You bud.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate, you could create a custom view in the active users section of the office 365 portal with a filter value of the incorrect license type.

Comment: Sorry but i have 12000 users to change. Creating a view and changing the license from admin panel is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

One liner to assigne the A1PLus license to the users who have no license or have A1 only. `get-msoluser -all | 
Where-Object {$_.userprincipalname -match '@students.test.com' -and ($_.licenses).accountskuid -contains 'test:A1' -and ($_.licenses).accountskuid -notcontains 'test:A1PLus'} | 
Set-MsolUserLicense -addlicenses 'test:A1Plus'`